# Group data and assign value based on column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried many ways to try and achieve the output i want but have been unsuccessful. I previously had a similar question although it was not as complicated as this, and so could not apply the same type of equation to achieve this output.

The rules are as follows:

For each group of  `Project_Id` (and stage order ) if the first cell in `Success` is 1, than make all `output` cells for that matching project_id  belonging to the same stage order a 1….If that first cell in `success` is 0 than make that particular group  0.

From this, If the group (  'stage order' for a particular project_id) has a 'success' of 0, than all `stage orders`(for that project_id) after this will be a 0 (IE If stage order = 2 for project id =1 is 0 , than stage orders that are 3,4,5 are all 0's.

The equation i have used, but is not right (I pasted this in the top cell and dragged it down)

```
=(COUNTIFS($B$3:$B3,B3,$D$3:D3,0)=0)*(COUNTIFS(B:B,B3,C:C,C3<>"",D:D,0)=0)
```

This should look like this:

| ProjectID (columnB) | stage order (columnC) | Success (ColumnD) | Output I want (ColumnE) | (Output from using the equation below: it is incorrect) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my interpretation of your question - reset all following values to zero if first success value in group is a zero, otherwise set all following values to first success value in proj ID.

```
=LET(proj,A2:A21,stage,B2:B21,success,C2:C21,rows,ROWS(proj),seq,SEQUENCE(rows),SCAN(,seq,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,INDEX(success,1),IF(INDEX(proj,c)<>INDEX(proj,c-1),INDEX(success,c),IF(AND(INDEX(stage,c)<>INDEX(stage,c-1),INDEX(success,c)=0),0,a))))))
```

or

```
=LET(
    proj, A2:A21,
    stage, B2:B21,
    success, C2:C21,
    rows, ROWS(proj),
    seq, SEQUENCE(rows),
    SCAN(
        ,
        seq,
        LAMBDA(a, c,
            IF(
                c = 1,
                INDEX(
                    success,
                    1
                ),
                IF(
                    INDEX(
                        proj,
                        c
                    ) <>
                        INDEX(
                            proj,
                            c -
                                1
                        ),
                    INDEX(
                        success,
                        c
                    ),
                    IF(
                        AND(
                            INDEX(
                                stage,
                                c
                            ) <>
                                INDEX(
                                    stage,
                                    c -
                                        1
                                ),
                            INDEX(
                                success,
                                c
                            ) =
                                0
                        ),
                        0,
                        a
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image]

You can make it more general by counting the actual number of rows including header(s):

```
=LET(count,COUNTA(A:A),proj,A2:INDEX(A:A,count),stage,B2:INDEX(B:B,count),success,C2:INDEX(C:C,count),rows,count-1,seq,SEQUENCE(rows),SCAN(,seq,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,INDEX(success,1),IF(INDEX(proj,c)<>INDEX(proj,c-1),INDEX(success,c),IF(AND(INDEX(stage,c)<>INDEX(stage,c-1),INDEX(success,c)=0),0,a))))))
```

Would need count-2 if there are two header rows etc.

Alternative version of the formula allowing for blank header rows (showing data starting at row 3):

```
=LET(count,COUNT(A:A),lastrow,count+ROW(A3)-1,proj,A3:INDEX(A:A,lastrow),stage,B3:INDEX(B:B,lastrow),success,C3:INDEX(C:C,lastrow),seq,SEQUENCE(count),SCAN(,seq,LAMBDA(a,c,IF(c=1,INDEX(success,1),IF(INDEX(proj,c)<>INDEX(proj,c-1),INDEX(success,c),IF(AND(INDEX(stage,c)<>INDEX(stage,c-1),INDEX(success,c)=0),0,a))))))
```

Comment: This looks very neat! Thankyou so much for this, it will be very helpful!!! One thing i did not mention in the post is that the columns of data i showed are constantly updating (ie they could be 20 rows one day or 30 the next). Is there a way to account for this in your equation? I initially tried to test this by extending the row value to A2:A210 (for example) but had a #spill result as you would imagine

Comment: Thanks! Yes you could make it so that it counted the number of rows and expanded downwards as you added more data. Will add to my answer.

Comment: Hi Tom,

Thankyou so much for your input! This worked really well, although when I have applied this equation, for some reason the last cell of gives a #Ref error. I saw your last note on changing the (count-2) and have played around with this (and other aspects of the equation) to see if I get it to apply the equation to the last cell of the column too but have been unsuccessful with that.

For the record, the row I paste this equation is in Row 3 (and so it references Row 3 of other columns), meaning row 1 and 2 are headers.

Comment: Maybe one of the header rows is blank in which case the 'dynamic' formula wouldn't work. I will add another version of the formula to my answer.

Comment: Thanks Tom! This has really helped me and i appreciate your guidance